# Geomashup Wordpress plugin search

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-geo-mashup

I am using Geomashup Wordpress plugin with my custom post types to display location of my posts.

I am also using plugin to display posts locations based on category. I wonder is there a way to add a search bar where someone can search posts by location, on custom maps..

Regards,

Josip

Answer (score 0):

There is a widget function that you can activate via the settings panel of the plugin

```
Enable Geo Search    Creates a customizable widget and other features for performing radius searc
```

Then you can search by given distance on entered or your current location.